# @property and setters and getters

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If I create a @property and synthesize it, and create a getter and setter as well like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
{
    NSString * property;
}

@property NSString * property;

--------------------------------

@implementation

@synthesize property = _property

-(void)setProperty(NSString *) property
{
    _property = property;
}

-(NSString *)property
{
    return _property = @"something";
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that this call

```
-(NSString *)returnValue
{
    return self.property; // I know that this automatically calls the built in getter function that comes with synthesizing a property, but am I correct in assuming that I have overridden the getter with my getter? Or must I explicitly call my self-defined getter?
}
```

is the same as this call?

```
-(NSString *)returnValue
{
    return property; // does this call the getter function or the instance variable?
}
```

is the same as this call?

```
-(NSString *)returnValue
{
    return _property; // is this the same as the first example above?
}
```

Comment: Of note: you don't need the `@syntehsize property` if you're manually defining `-(void)setProperty:(NSString*)` and `-(NSString*)property`.

Comment: But then, upon creating a property, xCode gives me a warning saying that the property must be synthesized...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code, not least of which is that you've inadvertently defined two different instance variables: `property` and `_property`.

Objective-C property syntax is merely shorthand for plain old methods and instance variables.  You should start by implementing your example without properties: just use regular instance variables and methods:

```
@interface MyClass {
    NSString* _myProperty;
}
- (NSString*)myProperty;
- (void)setMyProperty:(NSString*)value;

- (NSString*)someOtherMethod;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (NSString*)myProperty {
    return [_myProperty stringByAppendingString:@" Tricky."];
}

- (void)setMyProperty:(NSString*)value {
    _myProperty = value; // Assuming ARC is enabled.
}

- (NSString*)someOtherMethod {
    return [self myProperty];
}

@end
```

To convert this code to use properties, you merely replace the `myProperty` method declarations with a property declaration.

```
@interface MyClass {
    NSString* _myProperty;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myProperty

- (NSString*)someOtherMethod;
@end

...
```

The implementation remains the same, and works the same.

You have the option of synthesizing your property in your implementation, and this allows you to remove the `_myProperty` instance variable declaration, and the generic property setter:

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* myProperty;
- (NSString*)someOtherMethod;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize myProperty = _myProperty; // setter and ivar are created automatically

- (NSString*)myProperty {
    return [_myProperty stringByAppendingString:@" Tricky."];
}

- (NSString*)someOtherMethod {
    return [self myProperty];
}
```

Each of these examples are identical in how they operate, the property syntax merely shorthand that allows you to write less actual code.

Comment: In the case of the last example, I'm assuming that by creating your own setter i.e. -(NSString*)myProperty{ return [_myProperty stringByAppendingString:@" Tricky."]}  overrides the actual getter of the @property?

Comment: All of the examples are functionally the same.  There's no overriding going on; when you synthesize a property, the compiler will automatically generate the getter and setter methods *unless* you provide the implementation yourself.  In the last example, we provide the *getter* method ourselves and the compiler generates the *setter* method.

Answer (score 6):

`return self.property` – will call your overridden getter.

`return _property;` – accesses the property's instance variable directly, no call to the getter.

`return property;` – instance variable.

**EDIT**: I should emphasize that you will have *two* different NSString variables -- `property` and `_property`. I'm assuming you're testing the boundaries here and not providing actual production code.

Answer (score 1):

above answer elaborate almost all the thing ,  i want to elaborate it little more.

// older way

```
@interface MyClass {
    NSString* _myProperty; // instance variable
}
- (NSString*)myProperty; // getter method
- (void)setMyProperty:(NSString*)value;//setter method
```

@end

the instance variable can not be seen outside this class , for that we have to make getter and setter for it.
and latter on synthesis it in .m file

but now

we only used

```
  @property(nonatomic) NSString *myProperty;
```

the `@property` is an Objective-C directive which declares the property

```
-> The "`nonatomic`" in the parenthesis specifies that the property is non-atomic in nature.
-> and then we define the type and name  of our property.
-> prototyping of getter and setter method
```

now go to .m file

previously we have synthesis this property by using `@synthesis` , now it also not required it automatically done by IDE.

```
little addition : this `@synthesis` now generate the getter and setter(if not readonly) methods.
```